# How to animate the movement of anotations on the MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

How to animate the movement of annotations on the MKMapView?
When position of annotation is changed, then annotation moving to other position with animation?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to use these delegate methods for that `setRegion:animated:` & `regionThatFits:`

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Also mind you that the map update doesn't work with animation when using SIMULATOR. When you try `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` on the device, it does work with animation.

Comment: I does not whant moving the map, i whant move only annotations++

Comment: If you update the annotation's coordinate using a `setCoordinate` method (or equivalent), the map view will automatically update the position of the annotation on the view.

Answer (score 15):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564013/animate-removal-of-annotations/8564097#8564097) question has the answer.

Simply wrapping coordinate change in UIView animateWithDuration seems to work fine:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                 animations:^{
    myAnnotation.coordinate = newCoordinate;
}]
```