# Is there a way to add text using Paths Drawing

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have a map custom view that inherit from MKOverlayPathView. I need this custom view to display circle, line and text.

I already managed to draw circle and line using path drawing CGPathAddArc and  CGPathAddLineToPoint functions.

However, I still need to add text.

I tried to add text using

```
 [text drawAtPoint:centerPoint withFont:font];
```

but I got invalid context error.

any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `MKOverlayPathView`, I think the easiest way to add text is to override `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` and put the path and text drawing there (and do nothing in or don't implement `createPath`).

But if you're going to use `drawMapRect` anyway, you might want to just switch to subclassing a plain `MKOverlayView` instead of `MKOverlayPathView`.

With an `MKOverlayView`, override the `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` method and draw the circle using `CGContextAddArc` (or `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` or `CGPathAddArc`).

You can draw the text using `drawAtPoint` in this method which will have the required `context`.

For example:

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    //calculate CG values from circle coordinate and radius...
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = circle_overlay_center_coordinate_here;

    CGPoint centerPoint = 
        [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(center)];

    CGFloat radius = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(center.latitude) * 
                         circle_overlay_radius_here;

    CGFloat roadWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale);

    //draw the circle...
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, roadWidth);
    CGContextAddArc(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, 0, 2 * M_PI, true);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    //draw the text...
    NSString *text = @"Hello";
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [text drawAtPoint:centerPoint 
             withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(5.0 * roadWidth)]];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

In relation to a comment in another answer...

When the center coordinate or radius (or whatever) of the associated `MKOverlay` changes, you can make the `MKOverlayView` "move" by calling `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:` on it (instead of removing and adding the overlay again).  (When using a `MKOverlayPathView`, you can call `invalidatePath` instead.)

When calling `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:`, you can pass the `boundingMapRect` of the overlay for the map rect parameter.

In the LocationReminders sample app from WWDC 2010, the overlay view uses KVO to observe changes to the associated `MKOverlay` and makes itself move whenever it detects a change to the circle's properties but you could monitor the changes in other ways and call `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:` explicitly from outside the overlay view.

<sub>(In a comment on another answer I did mention using `MKOverlayPathView` and that is how the LocationReminders app implements a moving circle overlay view.  But I should have mentioned how you can also use `MKOverlayView` to draw a circle.  Sorry about that.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks Anna...I've used MKOverlayPathView to draw circle and it works fine. except I need to animate view movment. becouse currently the default user marker on map move in an animated way when location changes. Thus, my circle view should also be animated. I know that I need to use [UIView beginAnimations and [UIView commitAnimations]; but I don't know where to put this code. Do I need to put it for example before & after invalidatePath in MKOverlayPathView?

Comment: Normally yes, to animate a view you would use beginAnimations/commitAnimations (or the block based animateWithDuration) but this doesn't seem to work with MKOverlayViews (at least I don't know how).  However, if you don't mind using an MKAnnotation (with a circle image or circle drawing) instead of an MKOverlay, annotation view's can be animated smoothly.  For an example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564013/animate-removal-of-annotations.  Only problem with annotation is that the image/drawing will stay a constant size (like the user location blue dot).

Answer (score 1):

Pushing the context with `UIGraphicsPushContext` generated a problem for me. Remind that the method `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` is called from different threads in the same time so I had to synchronize the piece of code starting where the `UIGraphicsPushContext` is called down to `UIGraphicsPopContext` call.

Also when calculating the font size like in `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(5.0 * roadWidth)]` one should take into consideration the `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`, which for iPad, iPad2, iPhone3 is `1` and for iPhone4 - 5 and iPad3 is `2`. Otherwise the text size will be different from iPad2 to iPad3.

So for me it ended like this: `[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:(6.0f * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale * roadWidth)]`