# Animate coordinate changes to annotations on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is it possible to animate changes to the coordinates of an annotation on an MKMapView in iOS? Nothing in the API seems to indicate that this is possible, however apps like Uber seem to do this when showing car locations in their map. Perhaps they are calling setCoordinate: multiple times over a short time to give the appearance of animation taking place?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8564097/467105) by Vladimir may be useful.

Comment: Yes, simply wrapping the setting of the coordinate does end up animating the change on the map. I did not expect that to be the case since MKAnnotation is not a subclass of UIView. Apple must be doing something a bit special with it :)